# How to Save Special Character to Mysql Database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I am saving banner url in mysql php taking the url from a textbox input by insert statement but it is saving the url as below

```
&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.mywiuir.com/ptp/?r=pro2&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;https://i.imgur.com/PLMoHfN.gif&quot; width=&quot;468&quot; height=&quot;60&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
```

sign like `< or </ or > />` etc are escaping and is being saved as `&lt;` `&gt;` how  can i save this as `< or </ or > />`

below is my insert statement where `$banner_url` is getting from a textbox input

```
$set = array("user_id" => $user_info['id'],"title" => $item_price['days'].' Days',"url" => 
        $banner_url, "start" => $start_date,"expires" => $expires,"expire_int" => $expire_int);
$insert = $db->insert("login_ads", $set);
```

this is my form

```
    <form method="post" id="loginadform" onsubmit="return submitform(this.id);">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; background-color:white;" type="text" id="banner_url" name="banner_url" placeholder="Enter Banner Url" required>
```

and i am getting the banner input with below code

```
$banner_url = $input->pc['banner_url'];
```

Comment: It's hard to answer this with the information you have provided. The HTML entity encoding could be occurring in the `$banner_url` generation code, or in the `$db->insert` function. Without seeing that code it's impossible to know where the problem is.

Comment: edited my question

Comment: There is nothing wrong if its inserting in database like this. It would prevent you from cross site scripting.

Comment: yes i know but i need to insert with the characters for this case

Comment: Why not just convert it back to the original chars when you retrieve from dB?

Comment: any code example for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It good practise to insert HTML characters inside DB as HTML entities. However you may fetch data using [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). It will convert HTML entities to their corresponding characters.